# Spring not able to locate the xml configuration file

Tags: spring

[image: Folder structure]

I tried by placing the springConfig.xml in the WEB_INF as well as src directory, but still getting the IOException.

Code:

```
     public class DrawingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Triangle triangle = new Triangle();
        ApplicationContext context = new 
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springConfig.xml");
        Triangle triangle = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");

        triangle.draw();
        ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)context).close();

    }

}
```

Exception:

```
    Jul 23, 2018 11:33:18 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@179d3b25: startup date [Mon Jul 23 11:33:18 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 23, 2018 11:33:18 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [springConfig.xml]
Jul 23, 2018 11:33:19 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/D:/Learning/Workspace/Java%20Project/Spring2/SpringDemo/target/classes/trace-context.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [trace-context.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [springConfig.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from URL [file:/D:/Learning/Workspace/Java%20Project/Spring2/SpringDemo/target/classes/trace-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Learning\Workspace\Java Project\Spring2\SpringDemo\target\classes\trace-context.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at 

  org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:165)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304
```

Comment: `WEB-INF` isn't the classpath. Also only `src` doesn't do a thing it should be in `src/main/resources` (assuming you are using Maven or Gradle with a default setup).

Comment: If you read the exception error message carefully, you will note that the problem seems to be not finding a file named `trace-context.xml` and not your `springConfig.xml`. You must be referencing it in your `springConfig.xml` but it's not in your `resources` folder.

Comment: that was very silly of me, initially I was getting the IOException for springConfig.xml only, so later did not pay attention to it.
Thank you Strelok for pointing out that it is trace-content.xml. Got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify where is the resource path located within your project. More on this link
https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources